# How to update CMakeCache programatically

Tags: bash, cmake

I have been fighting with this issue for a while but so far I haven't found a good answer, so here we are...

I have been trying to compile a project using a single bash script, my requirements for it are:

- allow quick iterative builds and
- automatically update the CMakeCache.txt variables (defined as bash variables).

(This project has multiple branches so the variables and the CMakeLists.txt files can change from branch to branch. I don't control the root CMakeLists.txt file so I can't change the way the variables are defined.)

The first issue I faced is when should I run cmake, which I didn't want to do very often since it takes some time. After reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250081/when-should-i-rerun-cmake) it was clear to me that it only needs to be run once, so I added a condition to check if the Makefile already exists. If it does, cmake is not called (directly).

The second issue, and the one this question relates to, is how to keep the CMakeCache.txt variables updated. I thought that cmake must provide some command to update only the variables, but I couldn't find such command. As far as I could understand the recommended way is to use the cmake GUI to change the CMakeCache.txt variables.

After some time I remembered I could do it with other bash commands, so at the moment I'm checking the value of the variable in CMakeCache.txt and if it is different from what I expected it is updated. This way the CMakeCache.txt is only changed if it is necessary. Here is how the script looks at the moment (cleaned up for clarity):

```
#!/bin/bash

# variables
SOME_VARIABLE="some_value"

# clean build
if [ "$1" = "-clean" ]
then
    # Remove stuff
fi

# change directory
mkdir build
cd build

# run cmake if Makefile does not exist
if [ ! -f "Makefile" ]; then
    cmake .. \
    -DSOME_VARIABLE=$SOME_VARIABLE
fi

# update cmake variables
if ! grep -Fxq "SOME_VARIABLE:UNINITIALIZED=$SOME_VARIABLE" CMakeCache.txt ;
then
    sed -i "s/SOME_VARIABLE:UNINITIALIZED=.*\n/SOME_VARIABLE:UNINITIALIZED=$SOME_VARIABLE/" CMakeCache.txt
    echo Updated variable
fi

# run make
make
```

Is there a proper way of doing this? This is working but I feel that it is a bit hacky and that there should be a better way to do this.

Thank you for your time,
David

Comment: There is a little sense to update `CMakeCache.txt` and do not run `cmake`. Just use `cmake -D<var1>=<value1> -D<var2>=<value2>` for run update variable and run `cmake` at the same time.

Comment: What you mean is something like KamilCuk is suggesting right?

Comment: Yes, his answer talks about the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a proper way of doing this?

Just re-run cmake.

```
if 
    # run cmake if Makefile does not exist
    [ ! -f "Makefile" ] ||
    # or when variable differs
    ! grep -Fxq "SOME_VARIABLE:UNINITIALIZED=$SOME_VARIABLE" CMakeCache.txt
then
    cmake .. "-DSOME_VARIABLE=$SOME_VARIABLE"
fi
```

better yet, don't bind to specific generator:

```
if 
    # run cmake if Makefile does not exist
    [ ! -f "CMakeCache.txt" ] ||
    # or when variable differs
    ! grep -Fxq "SOME_VARIABLE:UNINITIALIZED=$SOME_VARIABLE" CMakeCache.txt
then
    cmake "-DSOME_VARIABLE=$SOME_VARIABLE" ..
fi

cmake --build .
```

Comment: *Facepalm* Don't know how did not remember this, much cleaner and very reasonable :) Thank you!